# How do I get distinct values in Azure Cognitive Search for pagination?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I've been stuck with this problem for a few weeks now and I have no idea how to solve it.
So basically, my index contains data that looks something like this:

```
[
    { id: 1, value: "some snippet from a paragraph"},
    { id: 1, value: "some different snippet from the same paragraph" }.
    { id: 1, value: "some different snippet from the same paragraph" },
    { id: 2, value: "some snippet from a different paragraph" },
    { id: 2, value: "some different snippet from id no.2's paragraph " },
    ... and a few more million values
]
```

As you can see, one "paragraph" is split into multiple chunks. Each item might have the same ID, but with different values.

I used $top and $skip, but the problem with this is that the values in the top n results will contain "duplicates". Like, the top 50 results will contain multiple items that have an ID of 1.
What I want to happen is that the top n results should only contain items with unique ID's. Is it possible to just get the item with the highest score of each ID? How can I make this happen?

The results should look something like this:

```
[   
    { id: 1, value: "some value" },
    { id: 2, value: "some value" }.
    { id: 3, value: "some value" },
    { id: 4, value: "some value" },
    { id: 5, value: "some value" },
    ... 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered modeling your schema so that each paragraph is a string element in a Collection(Edm.String) field? Each document would look like this:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "paragraphs": [
    "some snippet from a paragraph",
    "some different snippet from the same paragraph",
    "some different snippet from the same paragraph"
 ]
}
```

You can still target the "paragraphs" field with your query, but this will guarantee each top-level documents on appears once in your search results (regardless of how many "paragraph" matched the query).

Here's a link to the "Supported data type" page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types

Comment: can you recommend a query that does not require data restructuring?